# Can you avoid Wounds not caused by Raises?

Tags: 7th-sea-2e, injury

Page 180 of 2e says:

> When you face a Villain or Hero in combat, he may spend Raises to directly inflict Wounds on your Hero outside of a Consequence. You can avoid these Wounds by immediately spending Raises…

Does "*these Wounds*" mean only wound caused by spending Raises? Or can I spend Raises to avoid added Wounds?

For example, the Sanderis storm deal gives you the option to (page 226):

> Throw a bolt of lightning to knock back a creature…up to ten feet directly away from you. If the creature strikes something solid (such as a wall), it takes 3 Wounds from the impact…

Or the dueling maneuver Slash (page 235):

> When you perform Slash, deal a number of Wounds equal to your Ranks in Weaponry.

These Wounds are not caused by the normal 1:1 Raise-for-Wound spending.

**Can I spend Raises to avoid these *indirectly* added Wounds?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say you can spend Raises to avoid the Wounds of either/any action taken by a Villain/Hero. I do not see them as indirect, and even if they were, the book gives an example about the burning room (p. 172) where you can spend Raises to avoid "environmental" Wounds too, like the fire burning around your Hero.

But I now realise this is a poor example, as it pertains to Wounds taken from Consequences and not direct confrontation with a Villain.

That being said, I still think *these Wounds* apply to *any* Wound applied as a result of a Villain's action.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the tour and visit the help to see how this Q&A site works.  This answer would be improved if you cite where in the book that example is about the burning room. (page/section/chapter?).  Once again, welcome and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Thanks @KorvinStarmast, and sorry my answer was incomplete. The example was on page 172, but I now realise that even with the proper page, my example still not apply since it was about Consequences and how to avoid _those_ Wounds.

Comment: We use comments to help clarify and improve answers, a bit of teamworkd, and we hope you'll be participating more in the future.

Comment: I'm not an expert on the Wound system (it changed so many times...) but this sounds right to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can avoid those wounds, but only on a 1:1 basis.  So, if my Villain were to Slashes your Hero for 3 wounds, and you have two raises left this round you can only negate two of them, not spending one to negate the Slash